# How can fill combobox with multiple fields?

Tags: delphi, pascal

How can I fill a TComboBox with multiple fields> I have an ADOTable with 3  fields which are `ID`, `Name` and `Location`.

I use this code with one field :

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(Form6.ADOTable1.FieldByName('Name').AsString);
Form6.ADOTable1.Next;
```

it work only with one field but how can do this for 3 fields (id, Name, Location).

I want the result to be the same as shown in the image below, what is the appropriate code for this process

[image]

Comment: You can concatenate strings using the `+` operator. Or, you can use the [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format) function.

Comment: `IntToStr(Form6.ADOTable1.FieldByName('Id').AsInteger) + Form6.ADOTable1.FieldByName('Name').AsString + Form6.ADOTable1.FieldByName('Location').AsString` or `Format('%d %s %s', [Form6.ADOTable1.FieldByName('Id').AsInteger, Form6.ADOTable1.FieldByName('Name').AsString, Form6.ADOTable1.FieldByName('Location').AsString])`

Comment: it work thank you  Andreas Rejbrand